# NodeJS Stacktrace for UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js

I have a node application that is throwing the error below but I can't tell where it's coming from. My suspicion is that is has something to do with calls being made by the BigQuery lib we use.

Any suggestions on how to get a stacktrace for a timeout error in a 3rd party lib?

I've tried running node with `--trace-events-enabled` and the stack traces got no better.

```
2018-07-10T15:16:04.24-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR (node:66) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ETIMEDOUT
2018-07-10T15:16:04.24-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/request/request.js:845:19)
2018-07-10T15:16:04.24-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR at ontimeout (timers.js:427:11)
2018-07-10T15:16:04.24-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:289:5)
2018-07-10T15:16:04.24-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR at listOnTimeout (timers.js:252:5)
2018-07-10T15:16:04.24-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:212:10)
2018-07-10T15:16:04.24-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR (node:66) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

Comment: This is what the Promise method `catch` is all about. Figure out where the problem is and catch that error!

Comment: If I know where it was coming from I could add a catch. Any advice of tracking down an error like this?

Comment: Check that all your promises have some kind of catch, really. You can also use a really rough binary search: Delete half your program and if it still manifests, delete half again. Once you delete the thing causing the problem, you'll have a better idea of where to start. A more elegant way of doing this is to have unit tests (Mocha + Chai!) to exercise your code in smaller chunks before integrating.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the unhandledRejection event and trigger a stack trace.  Run  something like this during your program's startup:

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

UnhandledProcessRejection errors often happen if you make a normal call to an async function or otherwise ignore the promise returned by a function.  The solution will probably involve either using .then() and .catch() blocks or async/await.